# 'Pip' is Not Recognized as an Internal or External Command windows 10 CMD

Tags: python, cmd, pip, visual-studio-2019

Im trying to `import numpy as np` (im using VS2019 as the IDE) and I get the error `"No module names 'numpy'"`.  So I tried going to the windows cmd and did `pip install numpy` and I get the error: `"'Pip' is Not Recognized as an Internal or External Command."`  I tried watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emYR6vVHxp8), and have located my Python3 folder (I cant find Python27), but there is no `pip.exe` file in there, so now I don't know what to do.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+is+Not+Recognized+as+an+Internal+or+External+Command

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you accidentally did not add Python to your PATH. Below is a screenshot of the Python3 installation where there is a checkbox to add it to your PATH.
[image]

To check if python is added to your PATH run the following command echo %PATH%. If it is not follow [this](https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/) tutorial to add it to your path.

Comment: Tutorial is useless. There's no "Variable value" line.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you can run python in cmd you should be able to run `python3 -m pip install numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't add `pip` to your system variables, you need to `cd` to the location of your `pip.exe` in order to use it.

You should be able to find it in a folder called `Scripts`.

Comment: I dont know where my pip.exe is though

Answer (score 0):

On of my friends had the same problem. We simply reinstalled python on his Windows 10 laptop and we paid attention to add python to PATH and select an option to install pip with python. This worked pretty much, I think the python Win10 installer is sometimes a little bit to complicated on Win10.

Answer (score -1):

First check if pip is already installed by running this command

pip   - - version

If it is installed then change the os path and if not check if python is correctly installed or not by running this command

python   - - version

If python is installed then try this command

python get-pip.py

Comment: You can format code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K so it stands out from the rest of the text.

Comment: actually I wrote this on my phone